# Magento 2.2.6 Catalog Search indexer process unknown error - Notice: Undefined offset: 53

Tags: magento2, indexing, magento2.2.6

I'm currently using Magento 2.2.6.  I've recently encountered the following error while trying to reindex the **catalogsearch_fulltext**:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 53 in
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/Full.php
>   on line 384

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: same on my side .. maybe should check if no bug already reported in git for 2.2.6

Comment: I just downgraded back to 2.2.4 and is fine now; probably some time needs to pass before upgrading a store to the last version :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140726)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140726)

Comment: we have the exact same problem. Started this morning, we are on 2.2.6 and suspecting that it could be php-version related. We used to be on php7.0 but maybe our host switched us over to php7.1 without our knowledge. Have you gotten anywhere further with the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem today, but all products on frontend show a 404 page and i can´t edit any product.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140740)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the index and doing a full reindex?

```
bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime
bin/magento indexer:reset catalogsearch_fulltext
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule
```

Assuming you use schedule mode (which you should).

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting.  Unfortunately I have already tried this and it hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got to the bottom of the issue. It appears my hosting company had changed the version of PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.0.32 which Magento 2.2.x does not support. I updated to PHP 7.1.23 and all seems to be working correctly. This update also resolved 503 and 404 pages being shown on the frontend product info pages.

Comment: on my installation, updating to PHP 7.1 helped to fix the "Internal Server Errors" but it did not help to fix the Catalog Search Indexer error.  Have you double checked that updating has fixed this error?  By any chance, were there any 3rd party extensions/modules that you had installed?  I'm stuck as well, and the indexer error will not go away.